# How to get text from 'td' tags from 'table' tag on html page using Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

How to get texts from 'td' tags from 'table' on html page by using Mechanize gem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Nokogiri Parsing HTML table II](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062051/ruby-nokogiri-parsing-html-table-ii)

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8233949/128421

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost always use mechanize with [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/). This [guide](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/getting-started-with-nokogiri/) helped me get started.

Something like this should work (Untested):

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://www.google.com/")
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page.body, "UTF-8")
doc.xpath('//td').each do |node|
  puts node.text
end
```

More information on nokogiri [here](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/)

Comment: Thanks, Mechanize already uses nokogiri so it would be more correct to use xpath lookup from Mechanize

Comment: Thanks, saved me a couple bits. In the past, I always required it separately.